# Entity Framework Navigation Properties data refreshed/updated with second DB calls

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

Query from EF results a complex Entity that has few associated properties and some are null. When I call DB to get details of those associated complex objects, EF pumps data into my first collection, where previously data was null. And it causes a self-referencing issue when converting to JSON.

Say a student has many Courses and courses have instructors. And a course also has a list of students.
When I get courses of a student it gives me a collection of those student courses where `student.Courses` is null. Now when I get a collection of all courses from DB. `student.Courses` is now no more null. It has a list of courses.

I have 2 Questions

1. How to control this behavior in a way that collection one is not
   updated.
2. How to avoid self-referencing issue.

I am on dot-net core 3. And I have `SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` in place.

I want to avoid EF from doing the following

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties
>   to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context
>   instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a
>   navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or
>   all of the related entities were previously loaded.[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 1):

> How to control this behavior in a way that collection one is not updated.

Load your entities using No-tracking queries.

> No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a
>   read-only scenario. They're quicker to execute because there's no need
>   to set up the change tracking information. If you don't need to update
>   the entities retrieved from the database, then a no-tracking query
>   should be used. You can swap an individual query to be no-tracking.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

> You can also change the default tracking behavior at the context
>   instance level:

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

var blogs = context.Blogs.ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Can you include a repro in your question?